# Creating Report of all Objects in Ruby / Rails Application or Memory Leak Detection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory

I need to create a report of all Ruby objects during the life of a ruby / rails application.

FAIL #1 ruby-prof 
  worked great locally for this in a local spike on my system ( using this repo:  https://github.com/kikuchiyo/vim_game.git ), but then I set this up in a different environment and repo and I cannot get the `objects` reports to show up - they are always empty.

Does anyone know of a solid way to get a report of the number of objects in a Ruby / Rails application, or another way of reporting / detecting memory leaks in Ruby / Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [Oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink), it's a ruby memory analyzer

Comment: Thank you.  I'm looking into this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem I would consider [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof) as a second approach. But if you could run ruby-prof on your local configuration it may just be some configuration issue on your other environment.